# WZUNZIP -v "unsupported"

Tags: winzip

Here's a `cmd.exe` batchfile and its run results:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "w=&echo."
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (%~f0) DO ECHO(%%i
ver%w%
ECHO(%PATH:;=&ECHO(%%w%
DIR *.zip%w%
DIR /s \wzunzip.exe \wzcline*.dll%w%
wzunzip -v ancient%w%
wzunzip -v ancient.zip%w%
GOTO :EOF
```

Run results:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

C:\executable
C:\batch
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
C:\Window s\system32
C:\Program Files\WinZip
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin
C:\FPC\2.6.2\bin\i386-win32
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64
C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl\Win64
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Acronis\TrueImageHome\
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\RemObjects Software\Oxygene\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\opencobol\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\OwlyCI

Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 830B-46FA

Directory of c:\ttbackup\operational

20/04/2009 13:07 1,752,181 ancient.zip
1 File(s) 1,752,181 bytes
0 Dir(s) 129,259,110,400 bytes free

Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 830B-46FA

Directory of c:\batch

15/07/2013 04:00 13,224 WZUNZIP.EXE
1 File(s) 13,224 bytes

Directory of c:\batchbackup

15/07/2013 04:00 13,224 WZUNZIP.EXE
1 File(s) 13,224 bytes

Directory of c:\Program Files\WinZip

15/07/2013 04:00 13,224 WZUNZIP.EXE

Directory of c:\Program Files\WinZip

15/07/2013 04:00 2,571,688 WZCLINE32.DLL
15/07/2013 04:00 3,084,200 WZCLINE64.DLL
3 File(s) 5,669,112 bytes

Directory of c:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip

15/07/2013 04:00 2,571,688 WZCLINE32.DLL
15/07/2013 04:00 3,084,200 WZCLINE64.DLL
2 File(s) 5,655,888 bytes

Directory of c:\Windows

15/07/2013 04:00 13,224 WZUNZIP.EXE

Directory of c:\Windows

15/07/2013 04:00 2,571,688 wzcline.dll
15/07/2013 04:00 2,571,688 WZCLINE32.DLL
15/07/2013 04:00 3,084,200 WZCLINE64.DLL
4 File(s) 8,240,800 bytes

Total Files Listed:
11 File(s) 19,592,248 bytes
0 Dir(s) 129,259,110,400 bytes free

WinZip(R) Command Line Support Add-On Version 4.0 32-bit (Build 10562)
Copyright (c) 1991-2013 WinZip International LLC - All Rights Reserved

ERROR: option v is unsupported
Program is terminating!

WinZip(R) Command Line Support Add-On Version 4.0 32-bit (Build 10562)
Copyright (c) 1991-2013 WinZip International LLC - All Rights Reserved

ERROR: option v is unsupported
Program is terminating!
```

Translating, this is Win7 Home Premium, Here's my `PATH`, directory of .zip files, directory of all occurrences of `WZUNZIP.EXE` and `WZCL*.DLL`.

I *did* have an older version `WZCLINE.DLL` so I overwrote it with the 32-bit newer version. The run results do not vary whether this `WZCLINE.DLL` file is present or not.

The results of two attempted listings is shown.

I'm sure this used to work on earlier versions. It is documented as working with the version I have (Winzip 17.5) but no combination of the `-v` switch appears to be processed according to the documentation.

I've tried `-v` and `-V` and `-vb`, `-vr`, `-vi`, `-vm`, `-vt` - all with precisely the same complaint from `WZUNZIP`.

Sadly, WINZIP has started to ignore me, after first having requested the following:

```
Please provide some additional information.

- Please describe the exact steps you take to cause this problem to occur.

- What version of Windows and of WinZip are you running (you can check the
· WinZip version by clicking WinZip's Help, About WinZip menu item)?

- Are there any error messages that appear? If so, please include the full
· text of the error message and the title of the error dialog box.

- Does the problem happen consistently, or does it appear to happen randomly?

- Does it happen with all files, some files, or one file in particular? If
· the problem happens with one file in particular, can you tell me how to
· obtain a copy of the file?

- Are there any other applications running when the problem occurs?

Please provide the screenshot of the error message you are getting. Please use the following link which will gives you more information in this issue: http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/21/
```

Most of that information is in the report I sent them, so I really don't have much hope of getting competent support there. The only information I can provide in addition is

Yes, it happens consistently on every .zip I've tried it on. - And the Point,click and giggle version has no problem decoding those files.

No, nothing else happening on the system at all.

7zip appears to list the contents happily.

So - anyone with a cure for this error with WZUNZIP? How do I get a file listing for a .zip file

Comment: I believe this should be asked on Super User, voting to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After navigating through the endless canned responses, I finally got to communicate with a technician.

The problem was isolated to my haing changed the `PATH` sequence, and WZUNZIP was locating prior DLLs on the revised path, hence re-installing the CLI add-on was ineffective.

Uninstalled WINZIP, located all the stray `WZ*` elements and deleted them, reininstalled and sanity was restored.

(posted for the sake of those who may encounter a similar problem - as evidently some have, given there have been responses)